# Sybase/ALTER TABLE: how to turn an existing column from non-nullable to nullable?

Tags: sybase, alter-table

Hopefully the title has made it quite clear.

I would like to see an example of a alter table statement that can change an existing non-nullable column in a Sybase table  to nullable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Modifying the NULL default value of a column](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/23393#X):

> If you are changing only the NULL default value of a column, you do not need to specify a column's datatype

(Switching the example from the above link):

```sql
alter table authors
modify address null
```